# Prove for this problem If H and K are subgroups. Then [H∨K:H]≥[K:H∩K] using injective map?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If H and K are subgroups. Then
[H∨K:H]≥[K:H∩K]

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).